# Requesting resource from API server

Tags: reactjs, redux

In a very conventional pattern, you have a list of posts at `/posts` and a detail view at `/posts/1`. If you have an API server on the backend and React+Redux on the frontend, you probably fetch resources when you reach `/posts`. But what do you do when you reach `/posts/1`? If you landed `/posts/` first, you already have all the resources, so you can maybe do the following:

1. Have `posts` reducer that returns all the posts we fetched from API server
2. Have `currentPost` reducer that returns only the relevant post

To set `currentPost` you can dispatch an action that updates `currentPost` as soon as you click a `post` in the index view.

But if you landed `/posts/1` without going to the index page, or refreshed `/posts/1`, you don't have the resources that you load in the index page (i.e. `posts` reducer returns `[]`). To solve this, you can request `/posts/1` from the API server and set `currentPost` then.

**Question:** Did I understand the flow correctly? I am not sure if `currentPost` reducer is even necessary. Also, I am not sure if it's conventional to use the resources from the index page and request a single resource only when it's necessary.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. The call to `/posts` may not retrieve all the data you need to display in `/posts/1` so you would have to fetch the remaining stuff. The two reducers are definitely useful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get all data you need to display `currentPost` in `/posts` request, will be sufficient to have one reducer to avoid duplicating items.

In `postsReducer` you need to handle two actions:
 1. When you get all posts from server, your reducer should return them.
 2. When you get a particular post, just append him to all posts list and return resulting array.

```javascript
//reducers.js
function postsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVE_POSTS':
            return action.posts;
        case 'RECEIVE_POST':
            return [...state, action.post]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

`PostContainer` should dispatch an action to fetch `currentPost`. When currentPost post data will be fetched from server, you can pass it to your `Post` presentational component.

```javascript
// PostContainer.js
class PostContainer extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.props.post) {
            this.props.dispatch(loadPost(this.props.params.id));
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Post post={this.props.post}
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    // if you're using react-router, post id will be in `params` property.
    const id = ownProps.params.id;
    return {
        post: state.posts.filter(post => post.id === id)[0]
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostContainer);
```

`PostsListContainer` should dispatch action to fetch all posts from server. When request finished successfully, you will pass array with posts to `PostsList` component.

```javascript
// PostsListContainer.js
class PostsListContainer extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.props.posts) {
            this.props.dispatch(loadPosts());
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <PostsList posts={this.props.posts}
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        posts: state.posts
    }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostsListContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

A practical approach would be store all posts and request the missing ones. Supposing your `posts` reducer is something like this:

```js
function posts(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_ALL_POSTS":
      return {...state, ...action.posts}

    case "FETCH_POST":
      return {...state, [action.post.id]: action.post}

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

You could define 2 actions:

- One for requesting all posts (it may include pagination params)
- One for requesting a single post

```js
// Fetch all posts.
// 
// In this example we are expecting the response to be like:
// 
//   {
//     12: {id: 12, title: "Hello", content: "..."},
//     16: {id: 16, title: "Bonjour", content: "..."},
//     54: {id: 54, title: "Hola", content: "..."},
//     ...
//   }
//
// If you want to return an array instead of a map the you need
// to normalize `posts`.
// 
function fetchAllPosts() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch("/api/posts")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(posts => dispatch({type: "FETCH_ALL_POSTS", posts}))
  }
}
```

```js
// Fetch a single post.
// 
// Response would be:
// 
//   {id: 12, title: "Hello", content: "..."}
//
function fetchPost(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()

    // Check if the post is cached
    if (state.posts[id]) {
      dispatch({type: "FETCH_POST", post: state.posts[id]})
    }

    // Otherwise we must query the API
    fetch(`/api/post/${id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(post => dispatch({type: "FETCH_POST", post}))
  }
}
```

Then in your components (before mounting them or after the routing) you can call the above action to trigger the loading. Let's consider you want to show the list of posts:

```js
const PostList = connect(
  state => ({
    // Retrieve all posts as an array
    posts: Object.values(state.posts),
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    fetchAllPosts: () => dispatch(fetchAllPosts()),
  })
)(
  class PostList extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      // Load all posts if none were stored
      if (this.props.posts.length === 0) {
        this.props.fetchAllPosts()
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.posts.map(
            post => <PostItem key={post.id} id={post.id} />
          )}
        </ul>
      )
    }
  }
)

const PostItem = connect(
  (_, initialProps) => {
    return state => ({
      // Get the post data
      post: state.posts[initialProps.id],
    })
  }
)(
  class PostItem extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <li>{this.props.post.title}</li>
      )
    }
  }
)
```

Tada! The simple case is handled. Now if we want to display a single post, we read it from the store, or fetch it.

```js
const PostDetails = connect(
  (_, initialProps) => {
    // Read the post ID from the initial properties.
    // We could imagine another case where the ID is read from the location.
    const {id} = initialProps
    return state => {
      // May, or may not, return a post
      post: state.posts[id],
    }
  },
  (dispatch, initialProps) => {
    // Same as above, we need to retrieve the post ID.
    const {id} = initialProps

    // Prepare an action creator to load THIS post.
    const fetchThisPost = () => {
      dispatch(fetchPost(id))
    }

    return () => ({
      fetchThisPost,
    })
  }
)(
  class PostDetails extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      // Load this post if it is not cached
      if (!this.props.post) {
        this.props.fetchThisPost()
      }
    }

    render() {
      if (!this.props.post) {
        return <Loading />
      } else {
        return <PostCard />
      }
    }
  }
)
```